# ClojureScript property accessor function

Tags: clojurescript

I have a need to pass a property accessor to a function, for example:

```
(defn test [access]
  (.log js/console (str (access js/window))))

(test #(.-screenLeft %))
```

Is this the best way to do it? The following doesn't work:

```
(test .-screenLeft)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, yours is the canonical way to do it in Clojure.

In ClojureScript that's also typically the best approach; the major gotcha is that there are two ways to introduce properties in JavaScript and ClojureScript:

- index style -- `a["foo"]` / `(aget a "foo")`;
- dotted property style -- `a.foo` / `(.-foo a)`.

You need to make sure that you're not mixing them for the same property if you want your code to compile in advanced mode. (Mixing in the sense of introducing the property with one pattern, then accessing with the other.) This is because the Google Closure compiler feels free to rename properties introduced with the dotted property style, while those introduced with the index style it leaves alone.

NB. this doesn't apply to explicitly exported properties and symbols provided by the JavaScript environment (`js/alert` etc.).

Comment: This recently caught me off guard.  Is there documentation about this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your solution is fine, but you might like something like this a little better:

```
(defn test [access]
  (->> access name (aget js/window) str (.log js/console)))
```

By taking advantage of `name`, you can now access the property `screenLeft` any of these ways:

```
(test :screenLeft) 
(test 'screenLeft)
(test "screenLeft")
```

Comment: If `(name "asdf")` works (that is, `name` on non-symbol, non-keyword string), that is accidental and may change in the future. Additionally, accessing properties through `aget` may be problematic under advanced compilation -- or not, depending on how the property was introduced; you need to match that access pattern.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk - No idea where you got that idea about `name`. Take a look at the [docstring](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1552/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L5876): _"Returns the name String of a string, symbol or keyword."_ As for the `aget` bit, I'm not sure how that would be a problem, but it wouldn't surprise me if there were some edge cases where it breaks.

Comment: Oh, you're right about `name`, sorry -- I should have checked. As for "the `aget` bit", it's hardly an edge case; see for example [this post](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html) from the Closure Tools Blog. (See the "Mixed property access methods" below the "Coding style factors" subheading.) The recommendation for code using mixed access patterns (actually given right above that bullet and applying to all bullets) is to use simple optimizations instead of advanced.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk - The _mixed property access_ problem is really good to know about. That seems like a pretty big shortcoming in their compiler. I can understand not handling completely dynamic cases, but cases when you're using a string literal really shouldn't cause such a big problem.

Comment: In my understanding, it's by design. Non-munged literal properties are useful -- suppose you want to produce JSON or an argument for use in some JS library which will be present on the page (presumably holding a limited number of top-level symbols protected by externs) etc. And if you're already using a string literal, you might as well use a dotted property.